# Did Grothendieck overestimate topoi?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory

I was reading the Russian translation of Recoltes et Semailles and in the footnote where Grothendieck lists his 12 contributions (including schemes) we find the following lines:

> Из этих тем наиболее обширной по своей значимости мне представляется тема топосов, которая осуществляет идею синтеза алгебраической геометрии, топологии и арифметики.

Now, I am no Russian, but I translate this as follows "In my opinion, among these topics the most extensive, in terms of its importance, is the topic of topoi, which implements the idea of synthesis of algebraic geometry, topology and arithmetic."

I am aware that topoi allow us to efficiently package certain pieces of (what I would call) homological algebra. This can be used to establish certain properties of, say, etale cohomology which is useful in arithmetic geometry. A different sort of applications we find in mathematical logic. I am very ignorant of those but I heard there is a cool perspective on forcing using topoi.

The question is: do we have any independent evidence that Grothendieck's estimate of the importance of topoi is accurate?

To clarify, let us consider schemes. They are pretty much necessary if you want to have conceptually clear proofs of, say, Weil conjectures or Mazur's theorem about torsion points. You can try to prove the former in particular cases purely computationally (starting from the defining equations) and you would realize that this problem is difficult. I think it is not unreasonable to expect that you could try something similar with the latter. So, there exist applications of schemes that can be expressed in really simple language and you can convince yourself that trying to prove them in really simple language is not going to fly. This is why I, being a diehard concretist, have immense respect for schemes.

Do we have anything like this for topoi? Are there any applications of topoi that could be "dumbed down" in a similar way?

Comment: I find the following quote from the intro to Lurie's "Higher Topos Theory" relevant: "Classically, category theory is a useful tool not so much because of the light it sheds on any particular mathematical discipline but instead because categories are so ubiquitous: mathematical objects in many different settings (sets, groups, smooth manifolds, and so on) can be organized into categories. Moreover, many elementary mathematical concepts can be described in purely categorical terms and therefore make sense in each of these settings." You can substitute "topos" in place of "category".

Comment: French original: *Parmi ces thèmes, le plus vaste par sa portée me paraît être celui des topos, qui fournit l’idée d’une synthèse de la géométrie algébrique, de la topologie et de l’arithmétique.*

Comment: Related (though it doesn't answer the question): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29232/the-unification-of-mathematics-via-topos-theory/29553#29553

Comment: Following up on YCor's comment, I think your issue may be one of translation. I believe "portée" means "scope" rather than "importance".  I think Grothendieck's statement is uncontroversial.

Comment: @DustinClausen but then, later in the book Grothendieck says a lot of things about the importance of topoi (again comparing them to schemes) so you would think that topoi would utterly revolutionize algebraic geometry and topology (which they have not done yet, presumably).

Comment: I second the sentiment of Dustin Clausen. Grothendieck used to choose his words carefully. Topoi have known a cold welcome when they were introduced and have had an underwhelming impact in the subsequent years. There are mathematicians (among whom Laurent Lafforgue and Alain Connes) who are now making great effort to show that they are interesting and important objects. You will find many heuristic as well as mathematical justifications for such project on the website of the Italian mathematician Olivia Caramello [here][1].


  [1]: https://www.oliviacaramello.com/