# Interview of Connes, Caramello, and L. Lafforgue about topos theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory

In a recent [blog post](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/yet-more-topos-news), Lieven le Bruyn, discussing an interview with Connes, Caramello, and Lafforgue on *France Culture*, wrote

> Towards the end of the programme Connes, Caramello and Laforgue [sic] lament that topos theory is still not taken seriously by the mathematical community at large

So, what have they said about topos theory not being taken seriously?

---

Edit (YCor): here's a transcription of the involved part of the interview. I don't include an English translation but automatic translators should give quite accurate one.
***J***= journalist (Nicolas Martin, France Culture) ***OC***= Olivia Caramello, ***AC***= Alain Connes, ***LL***= Laurent Lafforgue

> **J:** On entendait parler dans ce reportage des topos, c'est très important, j'aimerais qu'on l'évoque maintenant, c'est la grande création, ce que Grothendieck disait être le plus fier d'avoir créé, une volonté unificatrice des mathématiques, et pourtant, paradoxalement, pour des raisons que vous allez peut-être pouvoir m'expliquer, les uns, les unes et les autres, ces mathématiques-là ont très mauvaise presse, aujourd'hui dans la communauté mathématique, il est difficile d'effectuer des recherches et de travailler sur les topos. Alain Connes, vous avez donné des leçons au Collège de France sur les topos mais ça n'a pas duré très longtemps; vous-même Olivia Caramello, ça a été difficile et vous aviez des pressions pour ne pas continuer dans cette voie. Comment est-ce que ça s'explique tout ça... euh, Alain Connes me fait signe que non.
>
> **AC:** Non non! en fait, si vous voulez, non. Ça c'est une version complètement externe de la réalité. La réalité, c'est que la notion conceptuelle de topos...
>
> **J:** ... que vous pouvez nous rappeler, brièvement, s'il vous plait
>
> **AC:** ah! Je peux vous rappeler ce que c'est... en gros, on avait, avant Grothendieck, l'habitude, pour regarder un espace — tout le monde sait que le rôle de l'espace est assez essentiel dans la géométrie et dans les mathématiques - avant Grothendieck, on quand on voulait connaître un espace, on le regardait directement, et on essayait de le comprendre. Ce que fait l'idée du topos, qui est une idée merveilleuse, c'est... elle met l'espace dans les coulisses, et ce que l'on fait, c'est des mathématiques ordinaires avec un paramètre, ce paramètre est dans l'espace en question: il est dans les coulisses. Pour vous donner l'exemple le plus simple possible, supposez que l'espace en question, ce soit simplement deux points, eh bien les mathématiques que vous faites: vous faites deux fois les mathématiques qui sont la théorie des ensemble ordinaire. Eh bien ce qui est merveilleux, dans la théorie des topos qui est là, c'est que, elle a deux caractéristiques. La première, c'est qu'en analysant ce qui se passe dans le contexte ordinaire de la théorie des ensembles, mais fait avec paramètre dans le topos, on arrive à une connaissance de cet espace (qui est l'espace des paramètres, qui est le topos) bien plus fine que si on l'avait regardé directement. Je ne peux pas m'empêcher de dire qu'en ce moment je suis en train d'écrire un livre avec un psychanalyste, Patrick Gauthier-Lafaye, dans lequel on utilise cette métaphore, mais par rapport à la psychanalyse. La deuxième chose, qui est absolument extraordinaire, dans cette idée du topos, c'est qu'elle revient à regarder le mathématicien au travail de manière structuraliste, c'est-à-dire: le mathématicien au travail va manipuler des ensembles, mais le structuraliste va se fiche du fait que ce sont des ensembles, il va regarder le mathématicien qui manipule des objets et des flèches et il va dire: ce mathématicien travaille sur ce qu'on appelle, en mathématiques, une catégorie, et, ce structuraliste va dire, mais quelles sont les propriétés de cette catégorie, qui font que le mathématicien peut travailler. Eh bien là on est au coeur des topos.
>
> **J:** Comment expliquer, alors, Olivia Caramello que les topos — alors corrigez-moi, évidemment, si je le décris de manière trop caricaturale — aient si mauvaise presse, ou soient un champ de travail thématique qui finalement a été très vite rejeté ou repoussé par les institutions?
>
> **OC:** En fait, j'ai réfléchi beaucoup par moi-même, en lisant Récoltes et Semailles, et aussi sur la base de celle ce qui a été ma propre expérience de vie. Effectivement j'ai reçu beaucoup d'oppositions, en fait, depuis le début de ma carrière, tout simplement parce que je voulais développer d'une façon globale et systématique cette théorie, justement dans le but de réaliser cette inspiration d'unification qui avait été déjà exprimée par Grothendieck, notamment dans Récoltes et Semailles. Donc tout mon travail de recherche a été dirigé vers le but d'élaborer des techniques, des méthodes, pour transférer des connaissances entre des parties complètement différentes des mathématiques par le biais des topos. Donc en fait, les topos peuvent être utilisés de façon incroyablement efficaces comme des objets-ponts pour relier des textes mathématiques les plus divers les uns et les autres. On peut penser métaphoriquement un topos comme un lieu dans lequel des points de vue différents se rencontrent en se reflétant les uns dans les autres. Donc je donne cette métaphore pour souligner cet aspect d'unification, car je pense que c'est celui qui a vraiment engendré le plus d'hostilité. Je pense que ce n'est pas la technicalité des topos en tant qu'objet mathématique comme d'autres objets — bien sûr il y a toute une technicalité, la théorie est quand même très sophistiquée, très profonde, sur le plan purement technique — mais ce n'est pas l'aspect technique qui a été à l'origine de l'ostracisme. Je pense que c'est vraiment cette dimension globale et interdisciplinaire qui dérange les gens. Aujourd'hui les mathématiques sont devenues hyper-spécialisées donc chaque spécialiste travaille dans son coin avec ses propres méthodes, il s'habitue à penser d'une certaine façon. Or avec ces ponts, qu'on arrive à engendrer avec les topos, on peut arriver notamment à démontrer un résultat dans un secteur des mathématiques en utilisant des mathématiques complètement étrangères à ce secteur-là. On peut arriver à établir des ponts entre des secteurs complètement éloignés en apparence et donc on peut arriver chez un spécialiste d'un certain domaine avec un résultat qui le surprend beaucoup, qu'on arrive à démontrer avec des méthodes qui ne sont pas les siennes. Donc vous pouvez déjà comprendre que ça peut être inquiétant pour certains si on n'a pas assez d'ouverture d'esprit pour accepter cette pluralité de points de vue. Donc je pense qu'il y a un certain dogmatisme, dans un certain cercle mathématique, qui fait qu'on s'habitue à un certain langage, et après, on se renferme, en quelque sorte, après des années d'hyper-spécialisation. Il faut quand même comprendre que travailler dans n'importe quel secteur des mathématiques aujourd'hui demande un investissement technique colossal, donc c'est quand même humainement compréhensible qu'on s'affectionne beaucoup à certaines méthodes et après on dit "je ne veux pas voir autre chose". Moi, ça m'est arrivé plusieurs fois que je donne des exposés ou par exemple je présente dans un domaine qui n'est pas le mien...
>
> **J:** par exemple?
>
> **OC:** la théorie des modèles, par exemple, ça m'est arrivé de démontrer un résultat parmi mes premiers, où je faisais une ample généralisation du théorème de Fraïssé, en théorie des modèles, qui est un résultat très important, et en fait, dans l'auditoire, je me rappelle bien, un théoricien des modèles important, qui ne pouvait pas croire que mon résultat était correct, parce que c'était trop général. Et en fait il a passé tout l'après-midi à essayer de trouver un contre-exemple, bien sûr sans y parvenir, parce que ma démonstration était tout-à-fait correcte... Sauf qu'il était formulé dans un langage que lui, il m'a dit "Je ne me mets même pas à essayer de comprendre, parce que de toute façon, je ne vais pas y arriver", il me l'a dit comme ça. Alors il a préféré passer quatre heures de son temps, il me tourmentait aussi parce que moi j'étais là, il essayait de me fabriquer tous ces contre-exemples, ça a été assez pénible (rire)... c'est juste pour vous donner une idée. Il y a vraiment ce côté interdisciplinaire qui dérange... en fait il y a beaucoup d'autres aspects évidemment.
>
> **J:** Laurent Lafforgue, un mot, parce que vous, vous avez quitté le milieu académique pour passer dans le privé, et parce que dans le privé, en l'occurrence, votre employeur vous demande de travailler sur les topos, et utilise cet outil, qui a l'air d'être particulièrement efficace, pour des travaux appliqués, qui ont l'air d'être des travaux passionnants et effectifs.
>
> **LL:** oui, c'est une histoire qui est totalement stupéfiante pour moi, que je n'aurais jamais imaginé il y a encore quelques années. Depuis une dizaine d'années, en fait depuis que je connais Olivia Caramello et ses travaux, je suis devenu, dans le monde académique, un fervent supporteur du développement de la théorie des topos, et comme toutes les personnes qui ont voulu développer les topos ou contribuer à leur développement, je me suis heurté pour cela à une très grande hostilité, et à ma totale surprise, j'ai trouvé, dans un milieu d'ingénieurs, en l'occurrence de la firme Huawei, en France, des oreilles beaucoup plus favorables. C'est une chose que je n'aurais jamais attendu, qui me stupéfie aujourd'hui encore. Et donc, depuis quelques mois, j'ai quitté le monde académique, je suis chez Huawei, mon environnement est constitué d'ingénieurs et de responsables de la hiérarchie de la recherche de Huawei qui sont totalement favorables au développement des topos, qui pensent dès aujourd'hui, c'est-à-dire seulement quelques années après avoir appris l'existence de cette théorie, qu'elle est extrêmement importante, et, certains parmi eux pensent que les topos de Grothendieck vont devenir, ou peuvent devenir, les mathématiques de l'intelligence artificielle. Donc, c'est-à-dire, quelque chose d'une importance absolument colossale. Pour moi c'est inimaginable, parce que ça fait 60 ans que la théorie des topos a été introduite par Grothendieck, qu'elle a été développée par lui, déjà à longueur de centaines et de centaines de pages, que lui-même, dont tout le monde sait qu'il est l'un des plus grands génies scientifiques de l'histoire a énormément insisté sur la puissance des topos, sur l'importance des topos, même au-delà des mathématiques. En fait dans Récoltes et Semailles, un certain nombre de pages sont consacrées à ça: Grothendieck dit pourquoi les topos sont tellement importants à ses yeux; il le dit dans des termes que les mathématiciens peuvent comprendre, mais aussi, que même un lecteur qui ne connaît pas les mathématiques peut être sensible à la beauté et à la profondeur de ce que dit Grothendieck quand il parle des topos. Donc il a écrit ses pages-là, et ça n'a eu aucun effet dans le monde académique. Donc là il y a un mystère, que Grothendieck lui-même ne s'explique pas: il constate cette hostilité, il ne la comprend pas. Olivia vient de proposer des éléments d'explication, mais pour moi ça reste un mystère. En fait les topos sont un sujet sensible et c'est bizarre, parce que, habituellement quand on dit qu'un sujet sensible, on comprend un sujet sensible c'est par exemple un sujet politique, sur lequel les gens ne s'accordent pas. On ne comprend pas qu'un sujet scientifique, qu'une définition théorique puisse être un sujet sensible, or en fait elle l'est. C'est un fait, que personnellement je ne m'explique pas, ou en tout cas, pas de manière satisfaisante.

Comment: How can the MO community know why those three mathematicians feel topos  theory is not taken seriously?

Comment: The current phrasing is extremely unsuitable for MO — very subjective and open-ended, and invites disagreement from the start by presenting a very debatable claim (“topos theory is not taken seriously”) as an assumed truth.  But it could be edited into something much more answerable and less controversial, as something like “What do Connes, Caramello and Lafforgue mean when they say that topos theory is not taken seriously?” — then anyone who’s been following the CCL work and debate can give an informed summary, without having to take a stance on how much they agree.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @JasonStarr's [objection](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416458/why-is-topos-theory-not-taken-seriously#comment1068502_416458) seems to apply even to the re-phrased question—how would we know what they meant?

Comment: @LSpice: Because they’ve spoken and written extensively on the topic.  A few years ago I could have written a reasonably confident answer — now I’d have to do a bit of catching up on their recent work, but someone who’s been following them more recently may very well be able to summarise what they’ve said on the topic.

Comment: One point of reference: in Ravi Vakil’s notes on algebraic geometry (“Rising Sea”) in the introduction he promises that you can “shoot him” if he ever uses the word topoi.

Comment: @SamHopkins Is that antipathy to the concept or to the declension?

Comment: @YemonChoi: in context the remark is about avoiding 'useless abstraction.' Here is the full quote: "Our general approach will be as follows. I will try to tell you what you need to know, and no more. (This I promise: if I use the word “topoi”, you can shoot me.)" (pg. 23 of http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf)

Comment: IMO rather than just vote to reopen, it might be more appropriate to create a meta thread on this topic.  I don't think I have much to add to this specific discussion but you could replace topos theory with a lot of other recent-ish ideas that hope to be seen as "foundational" and you'll encounter the exact same discussion, one generation after another.  There are some useful things to discuss here, but I'm not certain if people really want to have them on MO, as they're more sociological in nature.

Comment: If we interpret the question literally and narrowly ("what do they mean?") then I would think that the best way to answer it is to listen carefully to the [podcast in question](https://podcasts.apple.com/fr/podcast/grothendieck-la-moisson/id1134937775?i=1000551407104). Someone whose French is better than mine can perhaps summarize what they say toward the end of that podcast.

Comment: The title of the question is inaccurate, Connes did not say that in the interview (see the rough contents in the answer below).

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29232/the-unification-of-mathematics-via-topos-theory

Comment: I've reedited the title to avoid any premises. I changed it to "Interview of Connes, Caramello, and L. Lafforgue about topos theory". The question includes now premises but in a quoted mode, which seems fine.

Comment: These include serious accusations on a public media about the mathematical community in general. For this reason it should be possible to answer it (confirm, deny, discuss...), and therefore I believe the question should be reopened (possibly including more quotations, notably of the podcast?)

Comment: Here is a [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/lamethodeFC/status/1494327781689159696?s=20&t=5TybkeeXJPQvL1kwkLa9lw) (in French) with some quotations of the guests.

Comment: @sno I feel there is no hostility toward topos theory per se – maybe indifference at worst, and maybe not so different from what mathematical logic and general category theory face. Nor, I think, is there hostility toward topos theorists in general. But Olivia has been making grand claims for over a decade now, and if I may be frank, she has been very brash about it from the beginning. I think it would be good if you (or future readers with the same question) have a look at the old thread François G. Dorais linked above.

Comment: I've added a transcription of the relevant extract of the France Culture (= public French radio) podcast.

Comment: Isn’t this persecution complex quite common among pure mathematicians?

Comment: Is there still a question to be answered? Right now, the question posed is of the form "what have they said..." and in the body of the question itself is a transcription of the relevant portion of the interview. The answers also include more than one translation and summary. So is there more still to be answered? If not, would it be asking too much for the OP to accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 27):

The podcast in question can be found [here](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/la-methode-scientifique/grothendieck-la-moisson). Here is a very weak attempt at a summary. I'd welcome edits to correct or provide more detail. I worked backward from the end and didn't listen earlier than the following -- there might be relevant material earlier.

The context of this interview is the recent publication (2022) in France of Grothendieck's text *Récoltes et semailles*. In this text, Grothendieck criticized (sometimes severely) several mathematicians and complained about the attitude of the mathematical community in general.

Around 45:30, the journalist claims that topos theory gets very bad press and asks why to Connes, Caramello and Lafforgue. Connes says no, this is a completely external vision of reality. Prompted by the journalist, he explains what is topos theory, where one studies a space not by looking at it directly, but by putting him behind the scenes. One does ordinary mathematics, with a "parameter" which is in the space in question. This leads to a much finer knowledge of the space. He talks about topos theory's relationship to structuralism and category theory.

Around 48:50, Olivia Caramello is asked why topos theory has been rejected by the institutions. She says that she received a lot of opposition since the beginning of her career because she wanted to develop topos theory in a global and systematic way in order to realise Grothendieck's desire of unification. She talks about her own passion for topos theory coming from it providing a place for different mathematical subjects to come into contact, and the incredible efficiency of this theory. She says that the unifying character of topos theory has generated much hostility (she even speaks of ostracism). The reason is not the technicality of topoi as mathematical objects, but rather the global and interdisciplinary character, which disturbs people. Mathematics have become hyper-specialized, the specialist works with his own methods and gets used to think in a certain way. There is a kind of dogmatism in certain mathematical circles, which results in getting used to a certain language and some sort of withdrawing. Around 52:30 she recounts a story of a model theorist spending an afternoon trying to convince her that a theorem of hers was "too general" to be true and trying to produce a counterexample.

Around 53:30, the last question is posed to Laurent Lafforgue, and he speaks about encountering a unique "hostilité" towards topos theory among mathematicians. On the other hand and very surprisingly to him, engineers from Huawei reacted very positively when informed about this theory. Several among them think that Grothendieck topoi could become the mathematics of artificial intelligence. Lafforgue finds it unimaginable that Grothendieck insisted on the importance of topoi already 60 years ago, and it had no effect on the academic environment. In the text *Récoltes et semailles*, Grothendieck does not understand this hostility.

Apparently there will be a second podcast to continue the discussion.

Comment: “Grothendieck does not understand this hostility.” Do you mean Lafforgue?

Comment: @ThiKu Lafforgue said that referring to what Grothendieck wrote in the book. Lafforgue also does not understand it. I will edit.

Answer (score 12):

I think that part of the answer lies in the folk tale *Nail Soup*. I can provide you a nourishing mathematical supper, says the toposopher to the hungry research student, but first I need you to provide me with a handful of carrots, and maybe a pinch of this and a pinch of that, ... . I have much sympathy with the first answer, because excessive hype, even of a beautiful subject, opens the door to bad mathematics. Category theory in its early days was also received badly in some quarters. Please excuse these superficial remarks from one who retired from academia twenty three years ago.

Answer (score 6):

For interested people, I put here [Google translation of transcription](http://denisevellachemla.eu/RSAGOCLLAC-en.pdf) and here [Transcription in french](http://denise.vella.chemla.free.fr/RSAGOCLLAC.pdf).
Denise Vella-Chemla

Answer (score 6):

My answer to this question would be: perhaps the religious zeal of some of its followers, based on the following experience.

About 12 years ago, the John Templeton Foundation organised a nice meeting on the foundations of mathematics.  It was somewhat high profile with at least one Fields Medallist there.  Everyone got to present their pov (people into category, type, set, or topos theory).  Things were pretty civilised until the following was uttered:

Speaker: "... and in conclusion, topos theory is thus the most natural and direct way of formalising mathematics"

Myself: "But what about e.g. topics X and Y, which do not have straightforward formalisations in topos theory?"

Speaker: "Let me be more specific: Mathematics is natural if and only if it can directly be formalised in topos theory."

Answer (score -3):

**Q:** *Why is topos theory not taken seriously?*

The way this question is phrased seems too subjective, but I may point out that topos theory has been suggested as an alternative mathematical structure with which to formulate quantum theory. See the [Bohr topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bohr+topos) entry in nLab. It is not mainstream, but it is a serious development in the context of quantum logic.

Comment: This is a fine piece of mathematics, but I don’t see how it’s an answer to this question — it’s no more “serious” than hundreds of other papers or projects in the field.  If it has some particular relevance to the question that I’m missing, it would be helpful to mention that!

Comment: well, I answered before the question was revised; the original question was _"Why is topos theory not taken seriously?"_ and I just wished to point out one area of research where it _is_ taken seriously.

Comment: You are answering the question "Why should topos theory be taken seriously?"   The question is asking specifically why it is not.